# chain additional coroutines with restful interface in flask rest plus?

Tags: python, rest, websocket, python-asyncio, flask-restful

Is it possible to integrate coroutines with a flask restful interface? I’m trying to subscribe to web sockets that pull data together. This should then be accessible over a restful interface.

But I’m unsure how I can chain together the subscriptions that access the websockets and the event loop that handles the restful interface itself.  Any suggestions how this can be achieved would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer that I think might work. Maybe there are better ideas?

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='Sample API',
          description='A sample API',)


@api.route('/my-resource/', endpoint='my-resource')
class MyResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"response": cr.i}


def enable_coroutines():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        asyncio.ensure_future(cr.counter1())
        asyncio.ensure_future(cr.counter2())

        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()


class Coroutines:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 9

    async def counter1(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.i += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print("My Coroutine")
            print(self.i)

    async def counter2(self):
        while True:
            self.j += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(self.j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cr = Coroutines()
    coroutines_thread = Thread(target=enable_coroutines, daemon=True)
    coroutines_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```